# How to set up a Checkboxes and require Checked one or more

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following code (Three Checkboxes):

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => @Model.FirstSelected) @Html.Label("First:")
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => @Model.SecondSelected) @Html.Label("Second:")
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => @Model.ThirdSelected) @Html.Label("Third:")
```

I need a check with validation message to choose one or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to validate this before posting you can use javascript/jQuery.
Add an onsubmit event in the form like:

```
 onsubmit = "return validateForm()"
```

And use a javascript like:

(not tested)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    var FirstSelected = document.getElementById('FirstSelected');
    var SecondSelected = document.getElementById('SecondSelected');
    var ThirdSelected = document.getElementById('ThirdSelected');
    if (!FirstSelected.checked && !SecondSelected.checked && !ThirdSelected.checked) {
        alert("Please choose one or more.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

If you want to do it from the controller then you would do similar:

```
if (!yourmodel.FirstSelected && !yourmodel.SecondSelected && !yourmodel.ThirdSelected){
  //do your stuff here and return to the view
  ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Please choose one or more.";
  return View(yourmodel);
}
```

In the view have somewhere to show

```
@ViewBag.ErrorMessage
```